# Legend and controls overlapping at rcharts

Tags: r-markdown, rcharts, slidify

I have been trying to deal with the overlapping on legend and control using rcharts in slidify. The behavior under Chrome look like:

https://codemorecode.wordpress.com/2015/03/04/legend-and-controls-overlapping-at-rcharts/

However any change to metadata in the YAML front matter doesn't work. Any advice I'll very thankful. Cheers,

Juan-Carlos

Below is my yaml:

```
`---
title       :
subtitle    : AAD-UTAS PhD Program in Quantitative Antarctic Science (QAS) 
author      : Juan-Carlos Quiroz
job         : March, 2015
framework   : io2012
highlighter : highlight.js
hitheme     : tomorrow
widgets     : [bootstrap, quiz, interactive, shiny]
mode        : selfcontained
knit        : slidify::knit2slides
logo        : aad.png
biglogo     : utas.jpg
license     : by-nc-sa
ext_widgets : {rCharts: [libraries/nvd3, libraries/morris]}
runtime     : shiny
---`
```

Answer (score 1):

A way to avoid this problem is save your **multiBarChart** into an html file (you have 2 options **cdn** or **standalone**). The generated html file does not have any problems with controls overlapping. For example:

```
r1 = nPlot(Catch ~ Years, group = "Class", data = database, type = "multiBarChart")
r1$xAxis(axisLabel = 'Years')
r1$yAxis(axisLabel = 'Catch (tons)', width = 55)
r1$yAxis(tickFormat = "#! function(d) {return d3.format(',.2f')(d)} !#")
#r1$save('mydata.html', cdn = TRUE)
r1$save('mydata.html', standalone = TRUE)
```

Then you will need to reference the html file into your rmd file like:

```
---

## Embedded html

<iframe width="800" height="400" src = 'assets/mydata.html'></iframe>
```